# Js Timeout Display

Tags: javascript, yii2

I am not sure if this possible using my current method, but I am wondering if it is possible to show the timeout as a counter on page.

I am creating a page to show data entering the database in 15 second intervals however the timeout can be changed.

```
var counter = 15 * 1000

var autoRefresh = function(){
     clearInterval(interval);
     interval = setInterval(autoRefresh, counter);
     $.pjax.reload({container:"#content",async:false, timeout: 2000});
     return false;
 }

var interval = setInterval(autoRefresh, counter);
```

Ideally I need to show a countdown timer till the next refresh. Is it possible or is there an alternate route I can take to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only real way is to run your interval every second, display the countdown and, if 15 seconds have past, do what you want to do.

```
var counter = 15 * 1000;
var currentCycle = 0;

var autoRefresh = function(){
     currentCycle++;
     if (currentCycle >= (counter/1000)) {
         currentCycle = 0;
         $.pjax.reload({container:"#content",async:false, timeout: 2000});
     } else {
         console.log((counter/1000-currentCycle)+' seconds remaining');
     }
     return false;
 }

var interval = setInterval(autoRefresh, 1000);
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Many thanks for the speedy response it is most appreciated.